# how to use shrink_to_fit() in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

There isn't example in the [doc](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.shrink_to_fit.html).

And I don't seem to make it work by doing `df = df.shrink_to_fit()`. Does anyone know how to use `shrink_to_fit` method in a proper way please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way it is used.  It is meant to minimize the extra storage used under the covers of your data frame.  You can get the estimated size of the DF via:
https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.estimated_size.html

print(df.estimated_size())
df = df.shrink_to_fit()
print(df.estimated_size())

The amount that is saved will vary drastically depending on how the DF was created and manipulated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For me, the estimated size before and after are the same. That's why I thought it didn't work. Thank you for confirming and that I can use it this way without doubt now.